# Divisors and Picard Group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I was wondering if there exists any relation between the group of Weil divisors (and the Picard´s group) of an affine variety, and the group of Weild divisors (and the Picard´s group) of it´s projective closure.

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is a variety open in a variety $Y$, there is always a map from the group of Weil divisors on $Y$ to that of $X$ and the same for Picard group. The first map is onto, the second map may not be.

Comment: And what happens if the variety $X$ is closed?

Comment: If $X$ ic closed in $Y$, you still have map from Picard group of $Y$ to that of $X$, but not for Weil divisors.

Comment: Where can I find more information about this topic? Thank you for your time Mohan.

Comment: Most of these are easy and essentially follow from definitions. They will be mentioned in most algebraic geometry texts. If you are interested in rings (affine varieties), you will also find them in most K-theory books, at least for Picard groups.